# how to enable ls highlighting in Debian

Tags: debian

I'm a Centos user and have just started my first Debian install. In Centos the ls command lists output in color to indicate whether an item is a file, directory, symlink and if a file/directory is world-writable.

Here's an example...

[image: Centos directory listing in color]

How can I enable this color display in Debian? Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

Put it in your .bashrc

Or if you prefer create a file in your profile named .bash_aliases and put there your alias (by default in debian's .bashrc that gets sourced)

Comment: @Xoundboy If it worked, mark it as an answer

Comment: I tried before but it said I couldn't mark it as an answer for another 8 minutes! I only just got chance to come back

Answer (score 2):

Under Debian and derivatives (example: raspbian for Raspberry Pi), if you edit the /root/.bashrc file you'll find some line commented about "ls colorization". Just uncomment them and run "source /root/.bashrc" or relogin:

```
# You may uncomment the following lines if you want `ls' to be colorized:
export LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
eval "`dircolors`"
alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'
alias ll='ls $LS_OPTIONS -l'
alias l='ls $LS_OPTIONS -lA'
```

Answer (score 0):

uncomment those line in the file **.bashrc** of you home directory:

```
export LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'
```

and type: `exec bash` for reload you bash with colors